# coloring int and float cells based on rules in custom QTableView model

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to color `int` and `float` numbers in `QTableView` based on some rule.

I have following custom table model which works ok for pandas dataframe data source:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui

class PandasTableModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        QtGui.QStandardItemModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._data = data
        for row in data.values.tolist():
            data_row = [ QtGui.QStandardItem("{}".format(x)) for x in row ]
            self.appendRow(data_row)
        return

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self._data.values)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.columns.size

    def headerData(self, x, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[x]
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.index[x]
        return None
```

but when I add function for coloring:

```
def data(self, index, role):
    if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
        value = self._data.iloc[index.row()][index.column()]
        if (
                (isinstance(value, int) or isinstance(value, float))
                and value < 0
        ):
            return QtGui.QColor('red')
```

inside my `PandasTableModel` class, program still loads without errors only all cells are white and seem empty but filters on headers are still showing all unique values which means that data is loaded.

**EDIT**

Here is reproducible copy-paste example.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys
import pandas as pd

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pdtable = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        dataPD = [['tom', 10, 180.3], ['nick', 15, 175.7], ['juli', 14, 160.6]]
        df = pd.DataFrame(dataPD, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Height'])
        self.model = PandasTableModel(df)
        self.pdtable.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

class PandasTableModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        QtGui.QStandardItemModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._data = data
        for row in data.values.tolist():
            data_row = [ QtGui.QStandardItem("{}".format(x)) for x in row ]
            self.appendRow(data_row)
        return

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self._data.values)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.columns.size

    def headerData(self, x, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[x]
        if orientation == Qt.Vertical and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.index[x]
        return None

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row()][index.column()]
            if isinstance(value, (int, float)) and value < 0:
                return QtGui.QColor("red")
        else:
            QtGui.QStandardItemModel.data(self, index, role)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app  = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    main.resize(600, 400)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you comment out whole  `def data(self, index, role)` function you can see original dataframe in Gui App.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working solution:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys
import pandas as pd

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pdtable = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.pdtable.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)


        dataPD = [['tom', 10.0, 180.3], ['nick', 15.0, 175.7], ['juli', 14.0, 160.6]]
        df = pd.DataFrame(dataPD, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Height'])
        print(df.dtypes)
        self.model = PandasTableModel(df)
        self.pdtable.setModel(self.model)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


class PandasTableModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        QtGui.QStandardItemModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._data = data
        for row in data.values.tolist():
            data_row = [ QtGui.QStandardItem("{}".format(x)) for x in row ]
            self.appendRow(data_row)
        return

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self._data.values)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.columns.size

    def headerData(self, x, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[x]
        if orientation == Qt.Vertical and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.index[x]
        return None

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row()][index.column()]
            if isinstance(value, (int, float)) and value > 0:
                return QtGui.QColor("red")
        elif role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app  = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    main.resize(600, 400)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```